# ruby process when server is free

Tags: ruby, memory, cpu-usage, beanstalkd

I want to run a Stalker job, only when the CPU load is less so that the site wont be affected.

The job is to convert videos from any format to flv and mp4. so its a pretty expensive job.

how can i achieve this?

EDIT

is this a good way?

how about smthng like

```
load = `uptime`.gsub(/(.*): /,'').strip.split ' '
if (load[0].to_f < 0.7 && load[0].to_f < load[1].to_f) || (!args["max_delay"].nil? && total_delay > args["max_delay"] && load[0].to_f < 0.85)
  do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Run a separate Ruby interpreter process that does only the transcoding and run it with `nice -n 19` or perhaps `nice -n 12`.

You may want to lower your priority (raise the *nice* level) within Ruby code after already starting the interpreter.

Now, you *can* use `Process.setpriority` to change the interpreter's priority. But unless you are privileged or are on Linux and have the CAP_SYS_NICE capability, you won't be able to get back to normal priority.

A strategy for *that* problem might involve receiving some work to do, executing `Process` or `Kernel.fork`, lowering the priority, running the job, and then calling `exit`.

Comment: +1. In particular I like the last suggestion. It would clean up after itself.